# GTM - Trigger for All Pages That Isn't Root

Tags: regex, triggers, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to set up two triggers -- one to fire on homepage only, and one to fire on non-homepage page views.

The Homepage trigger (for root ie /) has the following rule:

```
Page Path matches RegEx ^/($|\?|#)
```

and the Non-homepage trigger has the following rule:

```
Page Path matches RegEx ^/($|\?|#)*
```

What am I doing wrong in the Regex for the non-homepage trigger? At the moment on the homepage, both homepage and non-homepage are firing.

Comment: Can't you just check the length of the page page variable? The root page ("/") should be the only one where this is 1.

Answer (score 0):

If your home page regex is `^/($|\?|#)`, that matches `/` at the start of string that can only be followed with `?`, `#` or end of string position, the opposite regex would look like

```
^/[^?#]
```

or, if whole match is required:

```
^/[^/?#].*
```

It will match a path that starts with `/` and the next char must be present and it should not be a  `/`, `?` and `#`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IKjVXZ/1) (note `\n` is added because the online test is performed on a single multiline string, you do not need it in your pattern).

[image]

Comment: this will still match the home page (just '/') so shouldn't it use .+ instead of .* to make sure there are characters after the initial '/'?

Comment: @Chrisvdberge `^/[^/?#].*` cannot match just `/` -  you may see it in the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/IKjVXZ/1). It cannot match a mere `/` because `[^...]` negated character class *consumes* a char (it does not behave like a negative lookahead that does not move the regex index). `.*` is enough.